# Selecting dragable element based on adjacent link text - Ruby Selenium

Tags: html, ruby, selenium, webdriver

I am automating some things for work with Selenium and I am attempting to drag a drop a list in sorted order. So I have a list of the link names and am looping through so that for each item I can drag and drop the [drag] element to the top of the page.

I can't figure out how to grab that [drag] handle element using the link_text ("Audit: " in this case).

I've tried selecting the desired element with the link_text locator and then using .attribute("id") to get the id which should be the same for the link and for the [drag] handle. The problem is that I am getting a blank string for the id instead of "evaluation_422"

```
reversed.each do |form|
    puts form
    eval = browser.find_element(link_text: "#{form}")
    id = eval.attribute("id")
    puts id 
    #returns blank string
end
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Below is the HTML I am trying to reference.

```
<li id="evaluation_422" class="evaluation">
<div class="right">
<span class="handle">[drag]</span>
<a href="/evaluations/422/edit">
<span>Audit:    </span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I finally solved this issue by grabbing the href of the link which happened to contain the number of the evaluation, so I was able to select the correct handle element using this:

```
reversed.each do |form|
    href = browser.find_element(link_text: form).attribute("href")
    eval_num = href.gsub("https://thisistheurl.com/evaluations/","").gsub("/edit","")
    handle = browser.find_element(xpath: ".//*[@id='evaluation_#{eval_num}']/span")
    top = browser.find_element(class_name: "evaluation")
    browser.action.drag_and_drop(handle, top).perform
end
```